# How to prevent saving data when ajax response is false?

Tags: php

I created a text filed for customer name. Already registered customer will show while clicking that text field. Only that registered customer can entry the data. I used ajax for prevent the new user addition.

this is the ajax:

```
function validateForm()
    {
        var customerName    =   document.getElementById('customerName').value;
        var customerId      =   document.getElementById('customerId').value;
        var getResponse=0;

        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           // document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
          getResponse= xmlhttp.responseText;alert(getResponse);

            if(getResponse=="0")
            {
                return false;
            }


          }

        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", "customer_check_ajax.php?name="+customerName+"&id="+customerId, true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
```

and here is the ajax page customer_check_ajax.php :

```
<?php
require("../../config/config.inc.php"); 
require("../../config/Database.class.php");
require("../../config/Application.class.php");
if($_SESSION['travelType']=='Admin')
{
    $check  =   1;
}
else
{
    $check  =   '';
    $logId  =   $_SESSION['travelId'];
    $proId  =   $_SESSION['proId'];
    $check  =   "proId='$proId'";
}

$cusName = $_REQUEST['name'];
$cusId   = $_REQUEST['id'];

$connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_DATABASE);
$qry="select * FROM ".TABLE_ACCOUNTS." WHERE ID='$cusId' and accountName='$cusName' and proId='$proId'";
$res = mysqli_query($connection, $qry);//echo $qry;
$num = mysqli_num_rows($res);
if($num>0)
echo '1';
else
echo '0';
?>
```

here i would get the responses as 0 for new user and 1 for already registered user. But i want to stop saving data when new user addition. Please help me.

Comment: Sorry I dont understand. You are not SAVING data anywhere in this code? Can you edit your question to make it  more obvious what your problem is. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are making Asynchronous request and the answer of the ajax will come after the function is over ..

To do what you want you must do synchronous ajax request

```
xmlhttp.open("GET", "customer_check_ajax.php?name="+customerName+"&id="+customerId, false); // `false` makes the request synchronous
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I did what you told. sorry. Still the new user can add and save the data.

Comment: I got correct response from ajax. But the problem is while response is '0' the saving process should stop. But i my case all the data are saved for the newly registered user.

Comment: The function validateForm() is called onsubmit in the form. So all the fields are inside the form is saving into database. The customerName that i created in this form that displays the customers who are already registered. But in my case is, a new user can save their details including the 'NAME'. But they should restrict for new customer name and saving. I think now u can understand my prb. Right? @  RiggsFolly

Comment: validateForm() is called on submit. if the ajax request is asynchronous the validateForm will continue when the ajax is sent and will not wait for server response. If you want to wait server response the request must be **synchronous** For more info [see examples here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request)